# Very confused regarding professor's instructions on classes and class parameters - Intro to C++ course

Tags: c++

We just started learning classes in this intro c++ CS class. I'm including much of the prompt for this project just in case it is helpful to answering my question, but I bolded the lines that I have specific questions on.

> Declare and define a class called Odometer. This class will have two
>   private variables, one for the miles driven and the other for the
>   gallons of gas pumped into the car. We are going to assume that the
>   car starts with a full tank, but these values begin at zero in the
>   default constructor. The member functions should include:
>
> • A constructor that takes initial values for both of the private
>   variables.
>
> • A default constructor that sets both values to zero.
>
> • A get_miles function
>
> • A get_gallons function
>
> • **An add_in_trip_miles function which increases the miles by the amount sent in its parameter**
>
> • **An add_gas function that records how much gasoline was pumped into
>   the tank.**
>
> • A mpg function that returns the number of miles per gallon
>   for the miles driven and the total amount of gas added to the tank.
>
> • A reset function which resets the miles and the gallons to zero.
>
> Write the class declaration at the top of your program and the
>   function definitions at the bottom. In the middle write a main which
>   declares an odometer object and then offers the user a menu n a loop
>   to allow them to chose to
>
> 1. See total miles
> 2. See total gallons
> 3. Record more miles driven
> 4. Record gallons pumped into the tank
> 5. See the average mpg that the car has gotten – this is a cumulative number based on the total number of miles driven and gallons pumped
>      into the tank since the odometer was lat reset, or the object created
> 6. Reset the odometer
> 7. Quit the program

So the two functions bolded essentially do the same thing, one increases how many miles have been driven and the other increases how many gallons of gas into the tank, both by user-inputed values. My question towards my professor, then, was why does the miles function require data sent into the parameter, while the gallons function does not? They are essentially the same, so I'm confused as to why they shouldn't either both pass a parameter, or neither pass one. Here are the those two functions in my code:

```
void Odometer::add_in_trip_miles(){
    double milesToAdd;
    cout << "How many miles would you like to add to the total?" << endl;
    cin >> milesToAdd;
    milesDriven += milesToAdd;
}

void Odometer::add_gas(){
    double gallonsToAdd;
    cout << "How many gallons would you like to add to the total?" << endl;
    cin >> gallonsToAdd;
    gallonsGas += gallonsToAdd;       
}
```

Currently the first one doesn't meet the project prompt, since it doesn't pass the value in the parameter, it just uses cout/cin in the function itself to get the value to add to the total. I figured i could meet the prompt by just putting the cout/cin in the int main(), and passing that value into the `add_in_trip_miles` function.

I emailed him about the confusion, and got the following response, which left me even more confused:

> There's a difference between input/output functions, which get
>   information from the keyboard/input-file or output information to the
>   screen/output file, and the set functions. I programmer can use the
>   set functions if they would like to do their own user interaction, or
>   if they are getting the information to be put into the object from
>   somewhere else - perhaps a calculated value.I was hoping that you
>   would implement both, which is what we usually do when we write a
>   class so as to give the application programmer the options.

Is he just asking for more functions that are input/output functions only, that then pass those input functions into `add_in_trip_miles` and `add_gas`? This email left me even more confused, since he mentioned (in the project prompt, above) each member function that was needed, and none of them are input functions.

Any guidance here would be great, my code currently does exactly what he wants it do to, but I don't want to be penalized because I didn't use functions in a certain way, etc. Let me know what you guys think and thanks for any help!

Comment: If you don't understand the exercise, you might want to ask *the professor* to clarify the issue.

Comment: @BoPersson They did, and were even more confused by the response

Comment: @M.M Exactly - starting to think I shouldn't have even emailed him since I'm even more confused now, haha.

Comment: He's saying that you should make these functions take the new value as parameter, instead of using `cout` or `cin` inside the function.  Because then people can set a new value without having to ask the user for it

Comment: @M.M So is that as simple as having the cout/cin inside the main, instead of inside the function? So it's essentially so other programmers can set a new value, as you say, without having to ask the user for it? Because without looking at the code, both ways do the same thing. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Odometer::add_in_trip_miles(double milesToAdd){
    milesDriven += milesToAdd; // assuming milesDriven is the private variable in your class!
}

void Odometer::add_gas(double gallonsToAdd){
    gallonsGas += gallonsToAdd;  // assuming gallonsGas is the private variable in your class!      
}
```

So if I did something like this

```
// Class up here
int main()
{
    Odometer myOdometer;//default constructor both values are 0.

    myOdometer.add_gas(5);// adds 5 to gallons of gas
    myOdometer.add_in_trip_miles(55);//adds 55 to miles driven

   // so if i did
   cout << "Miles: "<<myOdometer.get_miles() << endl;
   cout << "Gallons: "<<myOdometer.get_gallons() << endl;
   // should display:
   // Miles: 5
   // Gallons: 55
}

// Class functions down here
```

Maybe your professor wants you to do something like this

```
 // Something like this perhaps, missing 5,6
int main()
{
    Odometer myOdometer;//default constructor both values are 0.
    int caseInt = 0;
    char enterKey;
    do
    {
        cout << "1. See total miles" << endl;
        cout << "2. See total gallons" << endl;
        cout << "3. Record more miles driven" << endl;
        cout << "4. Record gallons pumped into the tank" << endl;
        cout << "5. See avg mpg" << endl;
        cout << "6. Reset the odometer" << endl;
        cout << "7. Quit the program" << endl << endl;
        cin >> caseInt;

        switch(caseInt)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << endl << "Total Miles: "<<myOdometer.get_miles() << endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << endl << "Total Gallons: "<<myOdometer.get_gallons() << endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                double moremilesdriven;
                cout << "Enter the more miles driven: ";
                cin >> moremilesdriven;
                myOdometer.add_in_trip_miles(moremilesdriven);
                cout << endl;
                break;
            case 4:
                double moreGallons;
                cout << "Enter how many more gallons pumped into the tank: ";
                cin >> moreGallons;
                cout << endl;
                myOdometer.add_gas(moreGallons);
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Must be [1-7], Please try again *How 'bout them Hawkeyes*" << endl;
                break;
        } // end switch
    }while(caseInt != 7);
    return 0;
}
```

Further modularization, *notice it isn't your class function but a function you are use to making without using the class directly, so you call your add with this function call since it is returning a double

```
double get_miles()
{
    double moremilesdriven;
    cout << "Enter the more miles driven: ";
    cin >> moremilesdriven;
    cout << endl;
    return moremilesdriven;
}
```

Now case statement:

```
case 3:
    myOdometer.add_in_trip_miles(get_miles());
    break;
```

Comment: This really helped me a lot. Thank you for your time, makes a lot of sense now

Comment: Np, it seems he may want something where you are actually calling a function for the input as well to further modularize it

Comment: I'm implementing the switch statement now (i had a mess of if/if elses previously), and the `cout << "Enter how many more miles were driven: ";` doesn't appear until after the case is finished. I'm running it through a debugger line by line and it doesn't make much sense to me. Here's the full case:       `case 3:
                cout << "Enter how many more miles were driven: ";
                cin >> milesToAdd;
                userInfo.add_in_trip_miles(milesToAdd);
                cout << endl;
                break;` and the cout doesn't come until after the function call.

Comment: Also note that the cin works, it just doesn't have any cout before it, rendering it completely useless. I enter a number and it is added to the total, but the cout doesn't appear until afterwards. I added a few test cout lines for the other cases and it isn't outputting anything until afterwards.

Comment: Wow, I added a \n to the cout and it worked, still no idea why a lack of an endline would cause it to not even output...